# Can't get cookies using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, tor, gecko

I am using selenium python, I create a **webdriver** using firefox binary and profile (**tor** browser), I get a webpage, I navigate and when I try to use

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

It returns an empty list, but if I check the webpage using dev tools in the Storage -> Cookies they are set, but if I use the console typing

```
document.cookie
```

It returns an **empty** string.
Is it a problem about tor browser that dont allow to use this kind of js codes or am I missing something?

Comment: they might have an "http-only" attribute set.

Comment: Yes, You are right